# Adding all elements of an array except the element at index with O(n) complexity

Tags: java, algorithm

This is what i came thru a problem in some coding test.

problem statement was like that we have to add all the elements of an array except the element at the index. subtraction operator cannot be used here and complexity should be O(n).

like 
`arr={3,7,8,4,9}
then result array will be... sum={28,24,23,27,22}`

i have think a lot over it. but still missing something. some hint or pseudo code will be appreciable.

Concluded:
if there is not any other reasonable answer to this then achieving subtraction by any mean could be possible solution. i have concluded it with using -1*arr[i] or complexity will be O(n2).

Edit: Above conclusion is not correct.

Comment: A simple `for` loop is O(n).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  yes, adding all the elements except the index. how could i do that in single run. and should be without subtraction operator.

Comment: Does `+ (-1*arr[i])` count as "not using subtraction"?

Comment: @AndyTurner  then what is the difference in using subtraction operator or -1*arr[i], its looks same... anyhow if it is so then i think problem statement was wrong... i am seeking if it is possible without any such methods. because that's make sense. thanks for help.

Comment: @pks if the problem statement is going to to forbid the use of the subtraction *operator* specifically, then achieving subtraction by other means seems entirely reasonable.

Comment: @AndyTurner - yes, if there is not any other reasonable answer to this then achieving subtraction by any mean could be possible solution. i have concluded it with using -1*arr[i]  or complexity will be O(n2).

Comment: Something like `+log10(1/10^element)`  instead of (-element) could work as a workaround for that subtraction constraint.

Comment: @Aphton - thanks for help but i guess a test to check algorithmic ability does not want to know if i know what ~ means or whether i know use of -1 or not. again discussion here is appreciable its clear my mind. i can rest in peace now.. lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple *O*(*n*) approach that uses only addition (and no "cheats" like `-1*elem` or `~elem + 1` to simulate subtraction) is to do two passes:

- Create the result array `sum`.
- In a "forward" pass from index 0 to index *n*−1, set each element of `sum` to the sum of all "previous" elements in `arr`:

  ```java
  int sumOfAllPrevious = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    sum[i] = sumOfAllPrevious;
    sumOfAllPrevious += arr[i];
  }
  ```
- In a "reverse" pass from index *n*−1 to index 0, augment each element of `sum` with the sum of all "later" elements in `arr`:

  ```java
  int sumOfAllLater = 0;
  for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    sum[i] += sumOfAllLater;
    sumOfAllLater += arr[i];
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Since the complexity of O(2n) = O(n), you can use one loop to calculate the entire sum.
Then a second loop after wards and set the value at the index as
arr[i] = totalSum-arr[i]

Edit: woops, did forget that you can't use subtraction.
But hey, subtraction is equivalent to an addition with the two's complement, LOL.

Edit: Here is the solution in python2

```
arr = [3,7,8,4,9]
sum = 0
for elem in arr:
    sum += elem

for i in xrange(len(arr)):
    elem = arr[i]
    elem = ~elem + 1
    arr[i] = sum + elem

print arr
```

Output

```
./bla.py 
[28, 24, 23, 27, 22]
```

Comment: exactly.. subtraction is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```java
package assignments;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sumOfArrayExceptItself {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n,i,j, sum=0,m=0;
        n=sc.nextInt();
        int arr[]=new int[n];
        int arr1[]=new int[n];
        for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
            arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
                sum=sum+arr[j];
            }
            int a = sum-arr[i];
            arr1[i]=a;
            sum=0;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1).replace("[", " ").replace("]", " ").replace(","," "));
    }

}
```